# applying function to multiple dataframes programatically

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

How can I apply the same function to multiple data frames in R without having to save the data frames into a new list? I don’t want to have to type out manually the names of the data frames, that I am applying the function against.  I don’t want to have to type:

```
data_frame2 = myfunction(data_frame2)
```

….Over and over.  I might have 30 dataframes I want to do this too.  I dont want to have to extract them out of a list.

```
data_frame.2 = mtcars
data_frame.111 = mtcars
data_frame.12345 = mtcars


my_function(dataset){
names(adjusted_dataset)= toupper(names(dataset))
return(adjusted_dataset)
}
my_dfs = ls(pattern = “data_frame.*”) # I know all my data frames in memory start with “data_frame”
```

How can I make use of `sapply(my_dfs, my_function)` here?

Comment: Any reason why you can't put all your data frames in a list to begin with, then `sapply`/`lapply` over that list, rather than having 30 different data frames as separate objects in your environment? I think many of us would *really* encourage a list-based approach

Comment: Why don't you put them into a list when you create them? Anyway, you can use mget to fetch them into a list. Btw. use glob2rx to turn your wildcard pattern into a regex (which is what ls expects).